# Firebase with Parcelable

Tags: firebase

sorry if I'm asking some stupid question.
Is it possible to pass the bean mapped by firebase through activities, something like:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot produtoSnapshot) {
Produto produto = produtoSnapshot.getValue(Produto.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("produto", produto);
... and start activity as well
}
```

I tried, but if I parcel the Produto class the Snapshot does not map. I think there is a way to the snapshot do the parcel task? I think is not a good idea to parcel the class, maybe because the snapshot is a parcel?
Thanks since now.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me,
Create another class ProdutoParcelable

```
public class ProdutoParcelable {
// which contains same attribs as Produto

    public ProdutoParcelable (Produto anotherProduto){ 
        /* Affectation here*/
    }
}
```

and make it parcelable,

```
ProdutoParcelable tmpProduto = new ProdutoParcelable(produto);
bundle.putParcelable("produto", tmpProduto);
```

*****HOPE HELPFUL*****